# Highlight points with facet_wrap - showing all points in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a plot using the mtcars data set where one level of cyl has been highloghted in a different colour and replotted over the top of all the points.

```
data %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(
    x = wt,
    y = mpg
  ) +
  geom_point(
    colour = "grey"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = data %>% filter(cyl == 4),
    colour = "tomato"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: example plot 1]

Is there a way such that if I were to make a facet_wrap like the one below, I could have each of the points in a facet highlighted like the ones above rather than just plotted on their own?

```
data %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(
    x = wt,
    y = mpg,
    colour = factor(cyl)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(
    ~ factor(cyl)
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: example plot 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the gghighlight package was made for

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = as.character(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  gghighlight() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You could first map all the points without the factor variable grey and after that color the points based on cal and use the `scale_color_hue` to have the factor color on each facet like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(
    x = wt,
    y = mpg,
  ) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars %>%
               select(-cyl), colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_hue() +
  facet_wrap(
    ~ factor(cyl)
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>